Earliest mention of or evidence for Water Libation/Simchas bais hashoeiva/Naanuim/Aravos
So far as I know the earliest explicit mention of these is in the tanaic/amoraic literature.
Is there any earlier mention of them or other kind of evidence?

Very very few things have mentions in pre Tannaitic literature. There's just so little of it.

@DoubleAA There's a fair amount. Most recently explored by Dr Malka Simkovich.

I don't know if this is the earliest piece of evidence, but it's probably one of the earliest.
Several scholars have argued that this type of Bar Kochva denarius (zuz, זוז) features either a lulav or an arava, and the flagon (צלוחית) used during the water libation ceremony of Sukkot (on the right).

For more information, see: Yonatan Adler, 'The Temple Willow-Branch Ritual Depicted on Bar Kokhba Denarii', Israel Numismatic Journal 16 (2007-2008), pp. 131-135.
